# Unable to create a Facebook App in App Dashboard

Tags: facebook, dashboard

Ok, so I'm using my personal Facebook account, that has a verified cell phone number. I can get to the App Dashboard page, and can click the "+Create a New App" button.  I complete the dialog using a name that get's green lit, and click the submit button.

I wait for a few seconds and I'm dumped back to the main App Dashboard page - no new App exists.

This is a personal account and not a company account.

Still stuck on this problem - any chance I could get a FB Dev Support help with this?

Comment: hVe you confirmed your account? youll need a card or a valid cell number

Comment: Yes - confirmed via cell & paypal.  If I use an uncofirmed account then I get a specific error.  This just displays an empty dialog and then returns to the dashboard.

Comment: @cwgso did you get this resolved? I am having the same issue, I can't even open a bug to report this.

Comment: @States - not yet -- I did get it enabled on a new account I'd set up after sending them a pic of my driver's license, but completely unable to get a response from anyone at Facebook regarding this.  I was unable to file a bug report, couldn't get them to respond to any tweets, no help what so ever.  You'd think they'd be able to afford some kind of developer support email.

Comment: Same problem here with seemingly no way to get it fixed: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/13301960/nothing-happens-after-creating-an-app-in-the-app-dashboard

Comment: Check your app name it shouldn't contains name like fb or something coz this is what happened with me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and finally got this working. Curiously, visiting the Facebook Developer App page https://facebook.com/developers?ref=ts&fref=ts using IE and going to the app fixed the problem. Using Firefox resulted in an infinite redirect. All of the apps I created but couldn't see started showing up.

Comment: Just tried it with IE and it works, so either IE was the solution, or just the passage of time - pretty sure I tried IE before without any luck... but either way it seems to work now.  Just need to delete all those test app's I created...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your account is too new. But usually you get an notice.

Comment: No, it's been around for a few years - just not very active.  I had someone else add me as a developer to their FB App, and that doesn't show up anywhere in my App Dashboard.